# There is no resource for path in Hybris

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I have the following controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value ="/{baseSiteId}/test123")
public class TestoccController {

    @Autowired
    private GetProductFacade productFacade;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<ProductDto> get(){
        return productFacade.getProducts();
    }
}
```

My extensioninfo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--
 Copyright (c) 2020 SAP SE or an SAP affiliate company. All rights reserved.
-->
<extensioninfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="extensioninfo.xsd">


    <extension abstractclassprefix="Generated" classprefix="Testocc" description="testocc extension"
               jaloLogicFree="true" managername="TestoccManager"
               managersuperclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.extension.Extension" name="testocc">


        <!-- you should add all required extensions to this list, except platform extensions which are automatically required -->


        <requires-extension name="commercewebservices"/>


        <coremodule generated="true" manager="org.training.jalo.TestoccManager" packageroot="org.training"/>


    </extension>


</extensioninfo>
```

The project is compiling and working but when I make an Http Call I am recieving this error:

`"There is no resource for path /occ/v2/electronics/test123/get"`

The controller was created using the ant extgen and selecting yocc.

In case someone knows what is happening I would apreciate the help.

I've already tried `ant clean all, cleaning IDE cache`

Answer (score 0):

Remove test123 and add into method level request mapping than try

Comment: I suggest that you post the code from the question with your corrections so that it is clear how to fix the code.

Comment: no result following the suggestion